# What's the Jquery equivalent of this

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I write this in clean jquery

```
document.GetElementById('A').innerHTML+=str;
```

Comment: It is not 'GetElementById' but 'getElementById'. Try to keep focus on the syntax while posting questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) if you just want to add more contents to the container element without changing the existing elements.

```
$('#A').append(str)
```

*Note: See my comment to VisioN's answer below*

Comment: Assuming what I'm appending to #A is an image, how can I append that image as a background to #A

Comment: Usually one doesn't append an img element to use as a background, one sets the background using CSS: `$('#A').css('background-image', 'url(somepath/someimg.png)');` (or by specifying the image in a class in the stylesheet and then adding the class to the element: `$('#A').addClass('bgi')`).

Answer (score 3):

Another way using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```
$('#A').html(function(i, html) {
    return html + str;
});
```

Comment: +1 this is the more appropriate equivalent because  `.innerHTML+=str` will remove all the attached event handlers of the inner content... where .append() doesn't do it... :)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I even don't know whether it is an advantage or downside here :)

Comment: It may not be relevant in this case... but just noted that there is a difference

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add some text in innerHTML then Arun's answer is right if you wish to get innerHTML then you can use

```
$('#A').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is enough.

```
$("#A").append(str);
```